# Postgres using cp1252 encoding?

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I have a postgres database that uses UTF-8 as encoding, and has client_encoding set to UTF8 as well. However, when using a script file that should be UTF8-encoded as well, it seems to assume the encoding is really cp1252, and gives me the following error:

```
FEHLER:  Zeichen mit Byte-Folge 0x81 in Kodierung "WIN1252" hat keine Entsprechung in Kodierung "UTF8"
```

What is wrong here? Shouldn't the DB assume the file is in UTF8, instead of trying to convert it from cp1252? I even added the line

```
SET client_encoding='UNICODE';
```

But that didn't change anything (as said, the database is already configured that way...)

Comment: You're correct that this error does not make sense when `client_encoding` is UTF8 (or UNICODE, that's the same for postgres). What happens if you add `show client_encoding;`  immediately before the query that errors out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually insert the BOM, then it worked. (What the heck!)